# Exclude repeated modulus values

Tags: actionscript-3, loops

I have an event firing that shows progress in a video:

_currentPosition = 3.86 seconds
_currentPosition = 4.02 seconds
_currentPosition = 4.16 seconds
etc.

What I'm trying to do is to send a notification to the server every five seconds, to indicate progress. I can round the seconds down to nearest integer using Math.floor. Then I can use modulus to get every fifth second. What I'm not seeing is how not to send a repeat for (e.g.) 5, since 5.02, 5.15, 5.36 etc. will all qualify.

I want something like the following, which is executing in a quickly-firing event, similar to enterframe. But I'm not sure how or where to do the test for _sentNumber, where to declare it, where to reset it...

```
    var _sentNumber:int;
   //_currentPosition is  the same as current time, i.e. 5.01, 5.15, etc.
var _floorPosition:int = Math.floor(_currentPosition); //returns 5
    if(_floorPosition % 5 == 0) //every five seconds, but this should only happen
                                        // once for each multiple of 5. 
    {
       if(_floorPosition != _sentNumber)       //something like this?
       {
        sendVariablesToServer("video_progress");
       }
    _sentNumber = _floorPosition;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there.  I'd just put the _sentNumber declaration inside the if statement:

```
var _sentNumber:int = 0;

private function onUpdate(...args:Array):void // or whatever your method signature is that handles the update
{
    //_currentPosition is  the same as current time, i.e. 5.01, 5.15, etc.
    var _floorPosition:int = Math.floor(_currentPosition); //returns 5
    if(_floorPosition % 5 == 0 && _floorPosition != _sentNumber) //every five seconds, but this should only happen once for each multiple of 5. 
    {
        sendVariablesToServer("video_progress");
        _sentNumber = _floorPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why *does* this work? int is a primitive datatype. Therefore saying var _sentNumber:int is like saying var _sentNumber:int = new int(). So each time it goes through _sentNumber should be re-initialized to 0, so this code should fail.

Comment: I thought you had just put the var _sentNumber:int at that location for simplicities sake!  Yes, you should definitely move that declaration out of the scope of the function, so that it does not get re-initialized.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var storedTime:Number = 0;

private function testTime( ):void{
  //_currentPosition is  the same as current time, i.e. 5.01, 5.15, etc.
  if( _currentPosition-5 > storedTime ){
    storedTime = _currentPosition
    sendVariablesToServer("video_progress");
  }
}
```